# How can I to confirm the execution of all observables in a cycle - (Angular 2)?

Tags: typescript, angular, loopback

In Angular 2, how can I confirm when "n" number of "observables" have finished:

```
  ...
  for (var i = 1; i <= this.quantity; i++) {
    description = this.prefix.trim() + ' ' + i.toString();
    point = new PointModel(description, 'A', this.locationModel.id);
    this.point.create(<PointModel>point)
      .subscribe(
      pointModel => {
        Materialize.toast('Se ha guardado el punto \"' + pointModel.description + '\"', 2000);
      },
      error => {
        Materialize.toast('Se ha generado un error: \"' + error + '\"', 2000);
      }
      );
  }
  ...
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
//create and fill points array
var points:PointModel[] = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= this.quantity; i++) {
  description = this.prefix.trim() + ' ' + i.toString();
  points.push(new PointModel(description, 'A', this.locationModel.id));
}

Observable.from(points).flatMap(point=>{this.point.create(<PointModel>point)})
.subscribe(
  pointModel => {
    Materialize.toast('Se ha guardado el punto \"' + pointModel.description + '\"', 2000);
  },
  error => {
    Materialize.toast('Se ha generado un error: \"' + error + '\"', 2000);
  },
  () => {
     Materialize.toast('All points have been created!', 2000);
  }      
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

My final code was:

```
  for (var i = 1; i <= this.quantity; i++) {
    description = this.prefix.trim() + ' ' + i.toString();
    points.push(new PointModel(description, 'A', this.locationModel.id));
  }

  Observable.fromArray(points).flatMap( //'fromArray' is deprecated, instead use 'from'
    point => {
      return this.point.create(<PointModel>point); //the return was the key here...
    }
  )
    .subscribe(
    pointModel => {
      Materialize.toast('Se ha guardado el punto \"' + pointModel.description + '\"', 2000);
    },
    error => {
      Materialize.toast('Se ha generado un error: \"' + error + '\"', 2000);
    },
    () => {
      this.loadPointsFromModelId(this.pointModel.id);
    }
    );
```